# Constraint layout ignores margins properties when specifying them from the properties inspector

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using android studio 2.2 p7 with `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'`
after using infer button it creates all the constraint perfectly. However the margin top value is not there in the layout xml. When I change it from the inspector theres no effect on the xml file while when I change it directly from xml file it works.

screenshot 
[image]

layout file

```
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    tools:text="@string/singapore"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:text="@string/singapore" />

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/singapore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/singapore_description"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:fontFamily="monospace" />
```

Any idea why the inspector margin top value is not being reflected in XML ?

Comment: I was having similar issues where the top margin kept getting reset to 0 whenever I added/changed constraints and I downgraded to [http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-preview-6](Android Studio 2.2 preview 6) and it seems to be working as expected for me.

Comment: Thank you I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug -- it should be fixed in the next release of Android Studio. Also think about moving to the latest ConstraintLayout library (e.g. alpha 6 or greater)

Comment: Great I moved to Alpha 6 and I can see the RTL positioning is solved. Thank you for all your efforts and support :)

Comment: Do you have a link to this bug report by chance?

Comment: @McAdam331 sorry for the late reply https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219619